# Connect textChanged function to a added class dynamically | PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

Only the "plugin2.py" file is working. Ignored "plugin.py"

`entry` just connected last assigned "x" value

I want all of my plugins connect to `textChanged` function. How can I do?

※ if change `self.x` to `x` not working but i don't get any errors.

※ if delete `self.x` variable and type:

```
self.entry.textChanged.connect((__import__(plug["name"]).Window().textChangedd))
```

result is the same, not working but no errors

```
pluginSystem/
    main.py
    plugin.py
    plugin2.py
    package.json
```

> **main.py**

```py
#imports

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.vBox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.entry = QLineEdit()
        self.vBox.addWidget(self.entry)

        with open("package.json") as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        for plug in data["Plugin"]:
            importlib.import_module(plug["name"])
            self.x = (__import__(plug["name"]).Window().textChangedd)
            self.entry.textChanged.connect(self.x)

        self.entry.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)

        self.setLayout(self.vBox)
        self.show()

    def textChanged(self, text):
        if text == "close":
            app.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

> **plugin.py**

```py
from pluginSystem.main import *

class Window(QObject):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    @pyqtSlot(str)
    def textChangedd(self, text):
        print("blabla")
```

> **plugin2.py**

```py
#Same as Plugin.py
```

> **package.json**

```py
{
  "Plugin": [{"name" : "plugin"},{"name" : "plugin2"}]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're code is not working because you need to keep a reference to all of those objects, as you're setting aways over `self.x`, the previous reference is being lost.

I've changed the structure of your project then I could make it work on my local environment.

```
plugin_system/
    main.py
    plugins/
        plugin.py
        plugin2.py
    package.json
```

**main.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QWidget, QApplication, QLineEdit, QVBoxLayout
import sys
import importlib
import json

class Window(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.vBox = QVBoxLayout()
        self.entry = QLineEdit()
        self.vBox.addWidget(self.entry)
        self.plugins = []

        with open("package.json") as f:
            data = json.load(f)

        for plug in data["Plugin"]:
            plugin_module = importlib.import_module(
                "plugins.{}".format(plug["name"])
            )
            plugin_object = plugin_module.Window()
            self.entry.textChanged.connect(plugin_object.textChangedd)

            #Keeping reference to all of the plugin objects
            self.plugins.append(plugin_object)

        self.entry.textChanged.connect(self.textChanged)

        self.setLayout(self.vBox)
        self.show()

    def textChanged(self, text):
        if text == "close":
            app.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = Window()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**plugin.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject


class Window(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def textChangedd(self, text):
        print("blabla1")
```

**plugin2.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject


class Window(QObject):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)

    def textChangedd(self, text):
        print("blabla2")
```